# Import Error in Cygwin

Tags: python, module, cygwin, importerror

When I try to launch python scripts from Cygwin, I get an import error, even though my script clearly imports the necessary modules:

`$ python Test_geo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_geo.py", line 8, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot`

When I run the script in idle, it works. AND, when I run the script in git bash, it works.

I have the relevant Cygwin packages installed:  `C:\cygwin\lib\python2.7`, which includes idlelib, as well as importlib.

Any ideas what the problem might be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git bash and Cygwin, can you compare the value of your environment variables that are related to python? I would try this in each system:

```
env | grep -i python
```

I suspect you'll find that Cygwin needs some additional paths set in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Okay, so, cygwin prints two environmental

Comment: Okay, so, cygwin prints two environmental variables.  One called 'PATH', and another called 'ORIGINAL_PATH'.                         Git Bash prints only the 'PATH' environmental variable.                  I'm not sure how to delete an environmental variable from cygwin...

Comment: That doesn't look like the problem. The importance is whether windows has any variable that relates to python, and if cygwin lacks that variable. It doesn't sound like that's the problem. Sorry I couldn't figure it out! Next, you could try looking up "python loading paths" (try a google search) to figure out what could cause it to not be found.